# Like '%Column values%'

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm new to SQL and I don't know how to do this and I didn't find any useful thread for me so I decided to ask.

Is there any possibility to replace this:

```
WHERE [Index] like '%9007870355%' OR
      [Index] like '%9005200803%' OR
      [Index] like '%9005780887%' OR
      [Index] like '%9007040256%' OR
      [Index] like '%9005200845%'
```

With something with the intention of

```
[Index] like %values from column in some table%
```

I'm trying to do this in my c# program to let user adding these indexes, and then take them from some table in my query, instead of editing query every time when some new index arrives.

Answer (score 4):

To implement

```
[Index] like '%values from colum in some table%'
```

do this:

```
join someTable on [Index] like '%' + someTable.someColumn + '%'
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It solves my problem